# Seperate the AutoResponder tab and the Inspector tab in fiddler

Tags: fiddler

while using fiddler, i have put a "break on all posts" in my filters.. and have saved some old responses for certain requests in my AutoResponders

A point to note about these requests is that all these requests go to the same URL with different Request body.. thus, although the URL is same for all these requests, their expected responses are different..

For this, i need to put a "break on all posts" and then as the requests are held by fiddler, i go to the AutoResponder tab and select the response which i want to put, then again go back to the inspector tab click on "run to completion".. then for the next request again i move back to the AutoResponder, click back the response i want to provide then again to inspector then "run to completion"..

if by some way, i could separate these two tabs - inspector and autoresponder, i can simply have these tabs stay side by side and do my tasks easier way..

if you have some other alternative too for my scenario, kindly suggest.

Comment: there is one alternative i have found.. i can simply click on the "GO" button in the main tool bar by selecting any URL for request.. unlike earlier where i clicked the URL came to the inspector tab, clicked the "run to completion" and went back to AutoResponder for selecting response for the next..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your AutoResponder match rule to use the `UrlWithBody` prefix so that you don't need a manual step.

Comment: oh.. i guess i will have to search this over google.. i am novice with fiddler so m unkown to many of the things.. thanks a lot for your reply.. will post back how it worked

Comment: Pardon my ignorance.. you mean - URLWithBody so that even if two URLs are same, fiddler will present different responses for two different requests? (yes, i understand that their request content should match) is it so ??

Comment: Using a `URLWithBody` rule permits a rule to evaluate the request body in addition to the URL. See http://www.telerik.com/forums/autoresponder-and-post#bBbx5bAl9kaEETZnwb3JRw

Comment: Bingo! thanks a lot EricLaw.. your reply helped ease lot of wrk!! and cheers to Fiddler.. really rocks!